# How to implement text highlighting in epub react reader?

Tags: reactjs, epub, react-functional-component, epub.js

I implemented react reader using [this](https://github.com/gerhardsletten/react-reader). Then I implemented highlighting text using [this example](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/blob/master/examples/marks.html).But I faced the following error:
TypeError: contents.mark is not a function

Can anyone to help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that example is pretty out of date.  You're better off looking at the "highlights" example.

The `mark()` function actually lives on the `annotations` object, which is part of the `rendition` and not the `content`.  `mark`, `highlight` and `underline` are all essentially the same thing, just styled a bit different.

You should be able to call `rendition.annotations.mark(cfiRange)`.